# Django {% translate "Log out" %} does not follow translation literally

Tags: django, translation

I am internationalizing my app and need to translate the string `"Log out"`. However, Django does not follow my translation literally but translates `"Log out"` in its own way.

In my specific example, I am trying to translate `"Log out"` to `"Esci"`, its Italian equivalent. However, when I render the templates I get the translation `"Annulla accesso"`, which roughly translates to `"Undo access"` in English.

Additionally, I found that if I use `{% translate "Logout" %}` or even `{% translate "Log Out" %}` everything works as I would expect.

Is there something particular about the string `"Log out"` that I should know? How can I override this behavior?

Here is my HTML:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{% translate "Hello" %}, {{ user.username }}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>{% translate "Currently logged in as" %}: {{ user.username }}</li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">{% translate "Log out" %}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is my .po file:

```
#: users/templates/users/user.html:9
msgid "Log out"
msgstr "Esci"
```

Again, despite this, when rendered, `"Log out"` is translated `"Annulla accesso"`.

Comment: `django.contrib.admin.locale.it` contains `msgid "Log out" msgstr "Annulla l'accesso"`… Looks like that's overriding your own translation in priority.

Comment: once you have created your `.po` files are you also compiling them into `.mo` files as well?

Comment: Shouldn't be my translation that override Django's? Is there a special syntax to add somewhere to solve this?

Comment: @RHSmith159 Yes I am compiling `.po` files. Everything works in fact, but "Log out".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [..] it looks for translations by following this algorithm regarding the order in which it examines the different file paths to load the compiled message files (.mo) and the precedence of multiple translations for the same literal:
>
> 1. The directories listed in `LOCALE_PATHS` have the highest precedence, with the ones appearing first having higher precedence than the ones appearing later.
> 2. Then, it looks for and uses if it exists a `locale` directory in each of the installed apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The ones appearing first have higher precedence than the ones appearing later.
> 3. Finally, the Django-provided base translation in `django/conf/locale` is used as a fallback.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations

Apparently the Django admin app is listed with higher precedence in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and its `Log out` localisation overrides yours. Change the order of installed apps, or add your app's locale path explicitly to `LOCALE_PATHS`, should the former solution pose any problems.